# ArrayList in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me

I have an arraylist of database records. I want to put it in my J2ME List. But there is no split or arraylist in J2ME. How can I do it? A code example would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better if you use `Vector` (`java.util.Vector`). It will help you.

Answer (score 4):

J2ME has `Vector`, which is the same as `ArrayList`, but all its methods are synchronized (a little bit slower).

Comment: @ali - you need an example for this???  Just code it the same as if it was a J2SE List.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Vector.html

```
public void asd(){
    MyObject mo = new MyObject();
    Vector v = new Vector();

    //Adds the specified component to the end of this vector, increasing its size by one.
    v.addElement(mo);

    //Returns the component at the specified index.
    mo = (MyObject)v.elementAt(0);
}
```